# nginx ignoring some websites

Tags: nginx, config, php

I have a serious problem.

It arised when I was editing a website. Suddenly the HTML wasn't rendered correctly and shortly after I only get the "Welcome to nginx!" default page. I tried renaming the website in ISPConfig and create a new one with the old domain, but still the same problem. The problem also arises, when I create completely new websites. Nginx is always redirecting to the default site.

But many other websites are working fine! Altough they have almost the same config...

I'm really confused and hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

I soluted the problem.

It was because of this line:
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9093;

I changed it to
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

And now it works o_O